# Coldfusion 8 JSON - convert return string to query object

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm relatively new interacting with other systems using JSON functions and maybe I'm just brain farting on a basic problem.

I access an API function that returns a query as a JSON string.  The return format is "plain".  The query runs to select a list of schools and creates an array of structures as the return string.

```
"[{\"city\":\"Adrian\",\"state\":\"MI\",\"school\":\"Adrian College\"},{\"city\":\"Albion\",\"state\":\"MI\",\"school\":\"Albion College\"},.........etc.
```

So now I need to convert this into a query object and work with it but now I just find myself going around in loops of google / test / re-google / re-test.  Any pointers on how to turn this into a query with school / city / state as the columns?

Comment: Keep in mind the backslashes means the quotation marks are being escaped. Since the return type is plain, sounds like the API thinks this should be a plain string passed to JavaScript, so it's taking a JSON object and "stringifying" it, rather than keeping it in JSON.

Answer (score 3):

First use [**deserializeJson**](http://cfdocs.org/deserializeJson) to convert the string to something usable.

Then, use [**StructKeyList**](http://cfdocs.org/StructKeyList) on the first array element to get the columns for use in [QueryNew](http://cfdocs.org/QueryNew).

Then do **two loops** - one through the array doing [QueryAddRow](http://cfdocs.org/QueryAddRow), containing an inner-loop through the columns which does [**QuerySetCell**](http://cfdocs.org/QuerySetCell) to set the values.

Along the lines of this:

```
<cfset Data = deserializeJson(JsonString) />

<cfif NOT ArrayLen(Data)>
    <cfthrow message="No data" />
</cfif>

<cfset Q = QueryNew( StructKeyList(Data[1]) ) />

<cfloop index="i" array=#Data#>
    <cfset Row = QueryAddRow(Q) />
    <cfloop index="ColName" collection=#Data[i]# >
        <cfset QuerySetCell( Q , ColName , Data[i][ColName] , Row ) />
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var=#Q# />
```

<sub>Ideally put it inside a function (which means var scoping as appropriate).</sub>

Comment: That's what I assumed - however deserializeJson fails: `"JSON parsing failure at character 1:'<' in
"[{\"city\":\"Adrian\",\"state\":\"MI\",\"school\":\"Adrian College\"}`

Comment: Then it's probably not valid JSON. What does [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) say?

Comment: character 1 isn't `<` - not sure what's going on there - however, if the actual variable contains `"[{\"city\"` etc then what you appear to have is a JSON string which contains a JSON object - i.e. it's been double encoded.

Comment: It's strange - if I use Firebug and create a string with the returned data, it works as expected.  `<cfset theString = '[{\"city\":\"Adrian\",\"state\":\"MI\",\"school\":\"Adrian College\"}}'/>`

Comment: jsonlint.com gives a parse error on the \.  If I do a Replace on the "\" it validates fine.  Could CFHTTP be adding something?  I have it set to  `result="httpResult"` and then I do the replace for \ on that.

Comment: I looked a bit into the API and the CFC has the return format set to plain.  The query is looped over building an array of structs which is then serialized into JSON and returned as a string.  No matter what I seem to do I keep getting that error about the '<' which doesn't seem to exist in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use the `DeserializeJSON()` method. More info [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_43.html).

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  There was a 2nd CFC that was proxying all of the API requests and verifying API credentials.  All of the API CFCs extended from that proxy CFC and the proxy CFC was missing returnformat="plain".

As soon as we had them put that in place the data came back as expected.  Thanks for everyone's suggestions.